# How complete is support for SVG on mobile devices?

Tags: svg

- How much of the [SVG specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/) has been introduced on the various mobile browers?
- Are there many known inconsistencies between these browsers?
- Are there any Javascript SVG libraries aimed at mobile browsers?

Comment: A partial answer here : http://caniuse.com/#cats=SVG

Comment: Anyone have an update on this for 2016?

Answer (score 5):

Most browsers will have support that at least matches SVG Tiny 1.1, and the features of SVG Tiny 1.2 that are also in SVG Full 1.1 (yes I know, that's a bit complicated — in short: Tiny is a subset of Full, but Full 1.2 was abandoned, leaving Tiny 1.2 with some features that Full 1.1 does not have).

There are inconsistencies in some of the DOM interfaces, in referring to external content (e.g. external  or fonts), and in animation support. Most of the rest tends to work pretty well.

As for libraries, it depends on what you want to do. On smartphones I would be surprised if Raphael didn't just work. For more constrained devices there's Ikivo's Enrich framework which isn't free but works well and integrates with their IDE if you happen to like those: http://ikivo.com/tools.html (disclaimed: Ikivo is a customer of mine).

You can also check this chart for support in general, it could be updated with more mobile information: http://www.codedread.com/svg-support.php.

Answer (score 4):

A quick look on caniuse.com usually answers these browser support questions
http://caniuse.com/#search=svg

Answer (score 3):

You should note that the default Android browser has SVG support turned OFF up until Android 3.

Answer (score 0):

Support documentation for Opera can be found [here](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/productspecs/).

Like Robin wrote, Raphaël should work fine on mobile. D3.js and most other js libraries that do svg work fine too, at least the ones I've tried.